# How can I store a large (2Mb) dataset in persistent local storage?

Tags: local-storage, indexeddb, lawnchair, localforage

I'm retrieving a large list of attendees for an event from a Firebase database - roughly 4,000 attendees. Each is represented as a JSON object of roughly 500 bytes.

After retrieving the dataset, I am trying to store it in a persistent local store. Initially I tried using Lawnchair.js using the standard DOM storage (localStorage).

What I've observed is that while inserting the dataset with this method, Chrome's *memory usage goes up to around 2GB*. Also, because saving to localStorage is synchronous, this blocks the DOM and the app becomes unresponsive for 30 seconds.

I thought it may be a Lawnchair issue, so I tried switching now to localForage using IndexedDB. This has had 2 great improvements:

1. localForage is asynchronous so the app remains responsive
2. Memory usage doesn't climb at all

However, it takes about *10 minutes* to write the data to indexed db. The first 5 minutes, CPU sits at around 30% and nothing is written to indexed db. The last 5 minutes CPU goes down and writing commences at a slow pace (maybe 10 records / second).

My question is thus:
Are these behaviours normal and if so, how can I store this data (roughly 2Mb) in persistent local storage without it either taking ages or consuming a huge amount of memory?

Comment: Interestingly I have found other people speaking about localForage being slow to write thousands of records to indexed db, e.g. https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/issues/301 .

Comment: After trying out this extension for batch inserting using localForage (https://github.com/thgreasi/localForage-setItems) and putting some performance counters in, I see it now only takes 17 seconds to "complete" inserting all 4000 records. 

However, if I check the indexed db record count, it still says 0 when my code completes. Watching the count I see inserts start happening around 25 seconds in and take a few minutes to complete.

Comment: Why not just use indexedDB directly? Why are you using an intermediate layer?

Comment: Good point Josh. I did consider it, but I figured localForage would probably have done a better job of handling the IndexedDB API than I would.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, I've narrowed down the problem to the fact that with localforage I've been trying to insert thousands of key value pairs, with the value being a JSON object. This takes a very long time. Rather call JSON.stringify(obj) first and insert the string as the value - more than 100x faster.

[image]